# SSRS show a error template instead of the real report if a stored procedure returns a null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I am sure this is achievable. I have a SSRS report which is fetching data which is well and good.  The report currently uses a parameter called BatchID, this parameter drives the report forward.  If the user enters a invalid BatchID or non existing BatchID the report currently shows the default template and the data fields are blank (This is expected so I don't see anything wrong).

The new requirement I have is to check whether the BatchID entered by the user exists or not. If exists show the report if not. Show a different report template which will read BatchID invalid or something other message.

I am happy to write the stored procedure, my question is how do I show different report templates based on a condition.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you use the same report and add visibility criteria to your items (Tablix,Charts etc.) based on this parameter (from stored procedure)? And for unexpected BatchID just show another item like TextBox with message.

Comment: It may be a better alternative to only allow the user to select a valid BatchId. Create another dataset containing all of the BatchId's and populate the available values of this parameter using the dataset.

Comment: Agreed. And this dataset could be even formed like an output parameter of the stored procedure, that's already written by @Abe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can use the same report, add visibility criteria to your items (Tablix,Charts etc.) based on this parameter (from stored procedure). And show another item like TextBox with message for unexpected BatchID.

Comment: Thank you all for looking into this. Thanks Alex, this is exactly what I have done. I have added a new parameter to my stored procedure (validateBatchID) based on the existence of batchID I set validateBatchID accordingly.  In the report I use validateBatchID in the field visibility expression to show or hide. This works perfectly fine. Thanks to everyone once again!!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a table or matrix to display the data then you can set the NoRowsMessage property on the tablix control with your error message.
When no data is returned this message will be displayed instead of an empty table.